# $R[\alpha,\beta] = R[\alpha][\beta]$ true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it true that for a ring $R$,  $R[\alpha,\beta] = (R[\alpha])[\beta]$? I know this is true for field extensions, but I'm not completely sure it's true for ring extensions.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Are you considering non-commutative rings?  If so, how do you interpret $(R[\alpha])[\beta]$? (it's possible there's a standard definition, but I don't know it and a short trip through the wiki lead me in circles)

Comment: Isn't that the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\monic}{\rightarrowtail}$

Once $R[\alpha]$, $R[\alpha,\beta]$ and $R[\alpha][\beta]$ are defined it's true by abstract nonsense.

---

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be drawn from $S$, i.e., we have the implicit extension $R\monic S$. Define a "category of $S/R$ intermediates" with

- objects the diagrams $R\stackrel{i_A}{\monic} A \stackrel{j_A}{\monic} S$ (or "just $A$") and
- morphisms those $f:A\monic B$ such that $i_B=fi_A$ and $j_A=j_Bf$.

Next, define

- $R[\alpha]$ to be initial among $S/R$ intermediates $A$ such that $\alpha \in A$,
- $R[\alpha][\beta]$, initial among $S/R[\alpha]$ intermediates $A$ such that $\beta \in A$, and
- $R[\alpha,\beta]$, initial among $S/R$ intermediates $A$ such that $\alpha\in A$ and $\beta \in A$.

Then

- since $\alpha\in R[\alpha,\beta]$, there is a unique morphism of $S/R$ intermediates $R[\alpha]\rightarrowtail R[\alpha,\beta]$ by the definition of $R[\alpha]$, so $R[\alpha,\beta]$ lifts to an $S/R[\alpha]$ intermediate $R[\alpha]\monic R[\alpha,\beta] \monic S$;
- since $\beta\in R[\alpha,\beta]$, there is a unique morphism of $S/R[\alpha]$ intermediates $\phi: R[\alpha][\beta] \monic R[\alpha,\beta]$ by the definition of $R[\alpha][\beta]$;
- since $R[\alpha][\beta]$ descends to the $S/R$ intermediate $R\monic R[\alpha][\beta]\monic S$ by composition with $R\monic R[\alpha]$, and since $\alpha,\beta\in R[\alpha][\beta]$, there exists a unique morphism of $S/R$ intermediates $\psi: R[\alpha,\beta]\monic R[\alpha][\beta]$.

Finally,

- by the definition of $R[\alpha]$, $\psi$ lifts to a morphism of $S/R[\alpha]$ intermediates, so we can compose to get a morphism $\psi\phi:R[\alpha][\beta]\monic R[\alpha][\beta]$, which must be the identity by the definition of $R[\alpha][\beta]$;
- by composition with $R\monic R[\alpha]$, $\phi$ descends to a morphism of $S/R$ intermediates, so we can compose toget a morphism $\phi\psi: R[\alpha,\beta]\monic R[\alpha,\beta]$, which must be the identity by the definition of $R[\alpha,\beta]$.

Altogether we have shown that the $\phi$ and $\psi$ defined above constitute a canonical isomorphism

$$R[\alpha,\beta]\simeq R[\alpha][\beta]\text{.}$$